# When I scroll recyclerview, I found an issue

Tags: android-studio-3.0

When I scrolls recyclerview using addonScrolllistener, the below method called only one time. Why is this?

```
@Override
 public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

}
```

Comment: Please provide all classes involved.

Comment: When scrolls recylerview  recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
              super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
              super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });

Comment: this method not called  public void onScrolled

Comment: ^ Please put your code into the question itself, using the formatting tools provided. Do ensure that all of your classnames are correctly spelled - I have corrected three spelling errors in your short post just now.